# Count occurrence of id in a complex array of objects structure(mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to check the amount of occurrence for a specific product id in a high complexity array of objects structure.

I tried with the aggregation functionality of MongoDB, but I only got the occurrences per document rather than the occurrences cross all the documents. The data structure of each document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4d67905a07f5dec1fcc763"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-01-27T08:16:11.706Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-27T08:10:56.553Z"),
    "pickupTime" : ISODate("2019-01-27T08:20:00.000Z"),
    "shop" : ObjectId("5c24b007b55ea3d7c599c95b"),
    "owner" : ObjectId("5c242e361ee775cdd8b047b6"),
    "total" : 350,
    "status" : "completed",
    "lineItems" : [ 
        {
            "product" : {
                "options" : [],
                "enabled" : false,
                "description" : "",
                "shop" : ObjectId("5c24b007b55ea3d7c599c95b"),
                "price" : 350,
                "name" : "Capuccino",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-01T21:56:31.928Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-01-08T12:14:53.322Z"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("5c2be20f8e52115849726fdc")
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c48efbc9efde32fab7ae47d"),
            "status" : "pending",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "config" : []
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

As you can see each document is a order, each order has lineItems that is a array of objects that contain the quantity of the desired product, the status of the current product, some configuration and the product itself. The product field is a snapshot of the product in the moment of the order as they may be changed by the supplier (cost, name description, etc.)

I currently tried the next aggregate formula:

```
{
        $group: {
          _id: {
            'product': '$lineItems.product._id'
          },
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }
```

But only returns the the occurrences of a product in each order, rather than cross all the orders. I understood I need to use $reduce to reformat the data structure, but I couldn't find a way how to organice my current data structure in order to make it match. Also I got said that after counting per product I can use the $sort to put the highest values on the top and then limit the search to the amount of records to return

The desirable result is get the top 5 most sold products based on the orders data.

Thanks.